# Android Studio: How do i let the room database autogenerate ID for records?

Tags: android-studio, auto-generate

I have this as the class where I want to let Room autogenerate ID.

```
@Entity(tableName = "mitglieder_table")
public class Mitglieder {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Vorname")
    private String vorname;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Nachname")
    private String nachname;

    public String getVorname() {
        return vorname;
    }

    public void setVorname(String vorname) {
        this.vorname = vorname;
    }

    public String getNachname() {
        return nachname;
    }

    public void setNachname(String nachname) {
        this.nachname = nachname;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Mitglieder(String vorname, String nachname) {
        this.vorname = vorname;
        this.nachname = nachname;
    }
}
```

The private int id is just used for the getter and setter.

Is this already enough to autogenerate ID or do i have to mention it in other classes? Do I have to include id in the constructor?

Thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is enough, the ID will be auto-generated, you don't have to include it in your constructor. If in the future you want to use any other constructor, you can declare it and annotate it with `@Ignore` and Room will ignore it.

Comment: Do I even need the getter and setter for the ID?

Comment: @LordGash I'm not sure, but try removing them, if it compiles without errors then insert an item, then query the id for the item that you inserted, and see if autogeneration still works.

Comment: I tried to compile without getter and setter - it didn't work so the getter and setter are necessary. Could you maybe also help me with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50295693/android-studio-tap-on-a-object-and-see-more-details-of-it

Comment: @LordGash Perfect! Good to know. I will try :)